# JavaScript If statement condition with no operator? What does it do?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am used to if statements having a condition where ( x < y ) or ( x == y ). But in cases where there is no operator, what does the if statement check exactly? i.e. in the example below if (window.XMLHttpRequest)... what's the condition?

Thanks.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
```

Answer (score 22):

As long as the expression inside the parentheses returns something other than `false`, `null`, `0`, `""` or `undefined`... the block in the `if` statement will be executed :-)

**In fact all of the following will work:**

```
<script>
  if (3) {
    alert('3');
  }
  if ({}) {
    alert('{}');
  }
  if(window) {
    alert('window!');
  }
  if(true) {
    alert('true!');
  }
  if('hell yeah') {
    alert('hell yeah!');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: See here for the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean

Comment: See [the MDN glossary entry for “Falsy”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). The full list of _falsy_ values as of ECMAScript 2018 is `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `false`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `document.all`. Future ECMAScript editions may add a [BigInt](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) `0n` to the list.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the JavaScript engine coerces any type into a boolean when testing a condition. It as if you were doing

```
// Coerce it to a boolean using !!
if (!!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
```

Comment: It is not the exact same case as doing that. OP's version converts to boolean (truthiness) and checks if that result is true. Your version converts both versions to numbers and checks if the numbers are not equal (`window.XMLHttpRequest` becomes `NaN` and `false` becomes `0`, `NaN != 0` is true).

Answer (score 1):

This checks whether there exists a property on `window` called `XMLHttpRequest` whose "truthiness" is true. Javascript interprets a variety of values as true: true, any non-0 numeric value, any non-null object reference, or (I think) any non-empty string.

In this case, the code is testing whether the browser supports the XMLHttpRequest property, which is the constructor function for an object that sends asynchronous requests to the server in the above-mentioned browsers. If the browser defines this function, the if statement will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

in some languages the predicate really has to return a boolean.
In javascript this isn't the case.

Some case like 0 or false (there might be others) are false, the rest is true