# Understanding `if (document.createEvent) {..}` function call without parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197511/5233188):

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        pom.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else {
        pom.click();
    }
}

download('test.txt', 'Hello world!');
```

Now I don´t understand the usage of `if (document.createEvent)`:

I read the answer for the question [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246928/5233188) and read some other questions.

In most examples is some kind of referencing like `window.onload = initAll;` or `var ret = Multiply;` but thats obviously is not the case here. The most interesting example for me was:

```
function Multiply(operator, operand) {
    return operator * operand;
}
var operator = 3;
var operand = 4;
var ret = Multiply;
```

Here, according to the author, `Multiply` does not get executed and `ret` reference to the function `Multiply`.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23645317/5233188) it is stated that calling a function without parentheses is a reference.

But thats get me confused even more, because for me a reference to `document.createEvent`, which is a function to create an event, does not make sense.

Documentations about the function `document.createEvent()` like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) does not point out the usage without parameters.

So, please bring some light to the darkness of my brain.
I appreciate your help.

Questions (short):

- Is `document.createEvent` a function call or a reference?
- What does `document.createEvent` return?

Comment: It's checking whether the document.createEvent function exists. It's not calling it at all. In Javascript functions are first-class objects and can be treated as such.

Comment: It's checking whether the browser supports `document.createEvent` and uses it if so, otherwise uses a different approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript If statement condition with no operator? What does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494614/javascript-if-statement-condition-with-no-operator-what-does-it-do) — it’s precisely the same technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - JavaScript has **truthy** and **falsy** values. Values such as 0, "", undefined, null are **falsy** values, while 1, -1, or "text", and for example an existing properties of an object are **truthy**. (if their values are not falsy!)
2- since *createEvent* is a property of *document* object, the code snippet basically tests the existance of that function, which means existance of it is something truthy. I assume this check is related to the browser compatibility & method deprecation.
you can read the details from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)

Comment: I decided that this answer is the best, because it references to what kind of return value is acceptable to let an if-statement evaluate "true". But I upvoted the other answers to, because there are all good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is `document.createEvent` a function call or a reference?

It is an attempt to access a property on the `document` object.

That property might exist. It might have a value. That value might be a reference to a function.

If all of those are the case, then it will be a true value (and the `if` block will run). If it doesn't exist, it will be a false value (and the `else` block will run).

**This is a test to see if the browser supports the function.**

> What does document.createEvent return?

The value of the property. If the browser supports `createEvent` then it will evaluate as the function, which is a true value.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `document.createEvent` a function call or a reference?

It's an expression denoting a property of the `document` object. One expects its value to be reference to a `Function` object that will create an event, but it may also be `undefined`.

> What does `document.createEvent` return?

As an expression, it evaluates to the current value of said property.