# Find next element with same class with empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html structure like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
  Upload Logo
  <input id="logo24" class="input-logo" name="options_24_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_24_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo27" class="input-logo" name="options_27_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_27_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo22" class="input-logo" name="options_22_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_22_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo25" class="input-logo" name="options_25_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_25_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo28" class="input-logo" name="options_28_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_28_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo23" class="input-logo" name="options_23_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_23_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo12" class="input-logo" name="options_12_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_12_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo26" class="input-logo" name="options_26_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_26_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo21" class="input-logo" name="options_21_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_21_file_action" type="text">
  <input style="display:none;" id="logo29" class="input-logo" name="options_29_file" type="file">
  <input style="display:none;" value="save_new" name="options_29_file_action" type="text">
</span>
```

the above html have input type file with same class name which is `input-logo`, the first input will show up at first, and when the input value change i want to hide it, and show next input which still has empty value to show up so i can input another file, so far i've tried this:

```
$('.input-logo').change(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   //get next class with no value and show it????
   //hide current element
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is a very strange way of achieving this common pattern. Why don't you append the new control at the end of the list when one is filled out instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $('.input-logo').change(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id');

     //hide current element
     $(this).hide();

     // check for null value
     $(".input-logo").each(function() {
       var input_val =$(this).val();
       if(input_val.trim()=='' || input_val==="undefined")
       {
         //perform action as you want
       }
       });
  });
```

Comment: Better use with `if(input_val.trim())` instead of `if(input_val.trim()=='' || input_val==="undefined")`  .Its check  `undefined,empty and null` [JavaScript If statement condition with no operator? What does it do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494614/javascript-if-statement-condition-with-no-operator-what-does-it-do)